# Does casting Tainted Strike on a creature with toxic keyword cause both toxic and infect to trigger?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When determining the effects of combat damage, given that toxic is defined as "Any time a creature with toxic deals combat damage to a player", does casting [Tainted Strike](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tainted%20Strike) on a creature with the toxic keyword allow both infect and toxic to give the defending player an arbitrary amount of poison counter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, damage to a player from a creature with both Infect and Toxic will cause that player to gain the poison counters for both abilities.**

[Rules 120.3b and g](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Damage) say

> **120.3b** Damage dealt to a player by a source with infect causes that source’s controller to give the player that many poison counters.
>
> **120.3g** Combat damage dealt to a player by a creature with toxic causes that creature’s controller to give the player a number of poison counters equal to that creature’s total toxic value, **in addition to the damage’s other results**. See rule 702.164, “Toxic.”

Comment: And if you give it poisonous also, it will give those poison counters as well!

Comment: also 113.2c, multiple instances of the same ability function independently. When that's not the case, the rules take pains to spell it out (e.g. 702.2f, multiple instances of deathtouch are redundant) and are, imo, usually intuitive anyway (possible sticking point would be lifelink, but if you see the fine-grained detailed of how it functions, it makes sense)

Comment: Lifelink *does*, however, stack with the [pseudo-lifelink](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22combat+damage%22+o%3A%22that+much+life%22) that was used before the lifelink keyword actually came into existence (and which also stacks with itself). (Not all of those search results are quite the same thing, but you get the idea.)